# Why does shiboken2 ignore C++11 style callback?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, pyside

I have a C++ library that uses C++11 style callback for functions. The callback definition inside a class is like this:

```
template<typename T>
using Callback = std::function<void (qint64,T,CallbackError)>;
```

I am trying to create a Python wrapper via shiboken2, but it seems that the Callback is not parsed at all, as all functions that use it in arguments are ignored stating:

> Unmatched argument type

How can I make shiboken2 aware of callback?

Answer (score 0):

figured out that c++11 is not supported at all!